# Tensorboard with pytorch in a MESS

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I'm working with `PyTorch` and visualize the training scalars such as loss in `tensorboard`. I have 3 models' event file lying in directory as follows:

```
├─data
│  └─tb
│      ├─baseline-cnn-cnn
│      │  └─large
│      │      └─20210121-04
│      │              events.out.tfevents.1611202426.node153.55453.0
│      │
│      ├─fim
│      │  └─large
│      │      └─20210120-04
│      │              events.out.tfevents.1611117755.node153.382325.0
│      │
│      └─npa
│          └─large
│              └─20210120-10
│                      events.out.tfevents.1611137925.node153.417110.0
```

I run tensorboard by

```
tensorboard logdir=data/tb
```

HOWEVER, the browser **shows figure of `npa` only although I've checked the `toggle all` button**. Moreover, **after I remove event file of `npa`, figure of `fim` magically appear!**

Somebody know why?? I'm really confused. **I'm pretty sure all of the event files are okay**.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I find when the event file grows too large, I must wait for a **long** time for the browser to load the data.